# Twig: How to fill up loops?

Tags: twig

How can I generate content within the content-file, to fill up the markup file?

**userlist-markup.twig**

```
<ul>
  what kind of loop?
    <li>user</li>
  what kind of loop? end
</ul>
```

**userlist-content.twig**

```
{% embed "userlist-markup.twig" %}
  ... what goes here?
{% endembed %}

or extend?
```

**page.twig**

```
{% embed "userlist-content.twig" %}
{% endembed %}
```

Comment: unclear but if you want to override the content of an included file with `embed` you will need to defined `block`'s inside the included template. Then you can overwrite them e.g. `{% embed 'userlist.twig' %}{% block example %}I'm an example{% endblock %}{% endembed %}`

Comment: Hm, I just want to create the content for the list. If I would use a block, I have to use the markup <li></li> in the content file. Thats what I dont want.

Comment: Why dont you just place `<ul>{% for user in users %}<li>{{ user }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>`

Comment: Yes, that was my first try. But then i struggled with: What do I have to do in the users-content.twig file? I guess I have to create an array there, but there is no stuff in the docs.

Comment: All variables known in you `page.twig` will be known in the included ones as well. Check [here](https://twigfiddle.com/hdqt65)

Comment: I dont get it. :( No I have another jason file? Where Do I have to place this code? Is it not possible to store the content direclty in the users-content.twig? :)

Comment: What are you talking about? `twigfiddle` is just a sandbox. You just need to pass the variable `users` to your main template. That's all

Comment: I just dont get it, sry. :/ But thanks a lot for your help! I will read the docs once again, maybe I will get it then..

Comment: Ok, Works with: {% set user = ["a", "b"] %}. :)